# Can't create new hardware profiles in AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

When clicking the Create New Hardware Profile button or the Clone Device button in Android Studio AVD (Windows platform) neither button does anything.  In looking for any log files which may indicate what is going on, I located the following folder and do see that upon launch, two thread-dumps are generated, but no logs are written when attempting to perform either function.

C:\Users\Bob.AndroidStudio2.1\system\log\threadDumps-20160718-072320-AI-143.2915827\freeze-20160718-072340-10

I have read through many posts on this and similar issues with AVD, including a defect from Google that was posted almost 2 years ago.  I have yet to find any solutions or work-arounds that will address this issue.

Has anyone found a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to resolve my issue while working with Android Studio in a Windows environment, so my resolution to this was to build/use a system which is running Ubuntu and now everything is working perfectly.